# Left side cannot be assigned for a record type

Tags: delphi

I am trying to upgrade my application from Delphi 2007 to Delphi 10 Seattle. I understand that a record needs to be copied to a local variable before changing and then assigned back. I am trying the same but I still get the error that I cannot assign to a left side. Could someone please help.

```
procedure TMydlg.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Msg:TMessage);
var
     MinMaxInfo: TMinMaxInfo;
begin
   inherited;
   MinMaxInfo := (PMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam)^);

   with MinMaxInfo do
   begin

      ptMinTrackSize.X := MinWidth;
      ptMinTrackSize.Y := MinHeight;
      ptMaxTrackSize.X := MinWidth;

   end;

   // Error here. Left side cannot be assigned to
   (PMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam)^) := MinMaxInfo;
```

TMinMaxInfo is from Winapi.windows

Comment: remove the brackets '(' and ')' around `PMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam)^`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is because you do not use a Record type and not a pointer type.

Change your code to this:

```
procedure TMydlg.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  with pMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam)^ do
  begin    
    ptMinTrackSize.X := MinWidth;
    ptMinTrackSize.Y := MinHeight;
    ptMaxTrackSize.X := MinWidth;      
  end;
end;
```

I've created a dummy test program:

```
procedure TForm9.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MinMaxInfo: pMinMaxInfo;
  Msg: TMessage;
begin
  MinMaxInfo := new(pMinMaxInfo);
  Msg.LParam := integer(MinMaxInfo);
  WMGetMinMaxInfo(Msg);
  Assert( pMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam)^.ptMinTrackSize.X = 10);
end;

procedure TForm9.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  MinMaxInfo: pMinMaxInfo;
begin
  MinMaxInfo := pMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam);

  with MinMaxInfo^ do
  begin

    ptMinTrackSize.X := 10;
    ptMinTrackSize.Y := 10;
    ptMaxTrackSize.X := 10;
  end;    
end;
```

Comment: *It is because you do not use a Record type and not a pointer type.* No, that's not it.

Comment: Perhaps you should read my answer closely to see that I did not copy what you wrote.

Comment: There aren't many ways to write the code. Furthermore, I started writing my answer before you made your edit. Back when you still had an assignment that was in essence: `ptr^ := ptr^`. The interesting thing is understanding the compiler error, which you missed. So yes, I think it was fine for me to write my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I actually enjoy reading your answers because you take the time to not just answer questions been asked but you also explain what is happening in various situations, for me I learn a lot from answers like yours because it helps better understand what the actual problems are and what approaches can be made to tackle them.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler error is emitted because the compiler rejects the outermost parens on the left hand side of the final assignment. In essence, your code is akin to the following:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
  end;

procedure Foo;
var
  rec1, rec2: TMyRecord;
begin
  rec1 := rec2;   // compiles
  (rec1) := rec2; // E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to
end;
```

Writing it in this simplified manner brings the issue into very sharp relief.

I'm not sure why the compiler rejects these parens. I suspect that the formal grammar of the language renders your left hand side invalid. Serg provides a plausible explanation in the comments, that is that `(...)` is an expression, and an expression is not valid as the left hand side of an assignment. I'm inclined to believe that is accurate.

Anyway, it is simple to fix your code. Instead of

```
(PMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam)^) := MinMaxInfo;
```

write

```
PMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam)^ := MinMaxInfo;
```

---

Note that it is not necessary to make a copy of the record, modify it, and then copy it back. You can modify the record directly, once you have cast `LParam` to a pointer to the record.

I would do so like this:

```
procedure TMydlg.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Msg:TMessage);
var
  pmmi: PMinMaxInfo;
begin
  inherited;
  pmmi := PMinMaxInfo(Msg.LParam);
  pmmi.ptMinTrackSize.X := MinWidth;
  pmmi.ptMinTrackSize.Y := MinHeight;
  pmmi.ptMaxTrackSize.X := MinWidth;
end;
```

I've omitted the `^` pointer dereference operator since it is optional in this scenario. If you prefer you might write the assignments like this:

```
pmmi^.ptMinTrackSize.X := MinWidth;
pmmi^.ptMinTrackSize.Y := MinHeight;
pmmi^.ptMaxTrackSize.X := MinWidth;
```

Comment: I don't think it is a compiler bug; a variable in parens is an expression, and an expression can't be on the left side of an assignment. It is not specific to a record type.

Comment: @user246408:  Yes, that's what I thought.  "Not an LVal" is the expression, IIRC.